# make a flip animation when navigating from view to view

Tags: iphone

please i have problem in making flip animation when going from a view to another, i explain :
 i have found a tutorial in this url : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rgnt3auoNw0
which explain me how to do, however the method of adding views in this tutorials and mine wasn`t the same, although i tried to put the code that he used in my IBAction so my IBAction looks like that :

```
-(IBAction)goToRechercherView{
[UIView beginAnimations:@"flipview" context:nil]; 
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft
                       forView:self.view cache:YES];
[self presentModalViewController:rechercherViewController animated:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

like that my app build succesfully but there is no transition when i navigate from my view where i have puted the iBAction, please help, thx in advance :)

Comment: it doesn't look like you've created rechercherViewController before presenting it.

Comment: Hi, no actually i have created it as a class, besides in .h of my main view i have imported it : #import "RechercherViewController.h" and i have instancied it : IBOutlet RechercherViewController *rechercherViewController

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't need any of the animation code. Simply do this before the presentModalViewController:

```
rechercherViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
```

Comment: AND how can i please manage the animation duration in this case ??

Comment: You should look at @Dancreek's answer if you want to customize the transition duration.  Setting .modalTransitionStyle will give you apple's style.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that will help is to change animated: to NO on the presentModalViewController: line.  I just ran into this yesterday in a similar scenario.  You are basically asking the OS to animate something that is already being asked to animate. This should help.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
 Yourviewcontroller *obj = [[Yourviewcontroller alloc]init];

    obj.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
     [self presentModalViewController:obj animated:YES];
```